# Centering and adding up numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a set of 2D arrays that I wish to add up but they are of different lengths. I want it to add up such that they are centered on top of each other. For example for 1D:

```
    a = [1,1,1,1,1]
    b = [2,2,2]
```

therefore:
c = [1,3,3,3,1]

I'm not sure how to approach this using numpy?

Comment: What do you mean by add up? I would think c is `[1, 3, 3, 3, 1]` if you're actually adding them. Can you clarify?

Comment: What if one of the inputs is even size and the other is odd size in some dimension? And what exactly do you hope to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Sorry thats what i meant and I'm trying to sum up images

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for your *add up* operation 0 is neutral element, for centering part you might harness `numpy.pad` in `constant` mode, as long as all dimension are odd. Consider following example, lets say we have (3,5)-shaped array and we want to obtain (11,9)-shaped array then we might do:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((3,5),dtype=int)
a_h, a_w = a.shape
required_h = 11
required_w = 9
vert_pad_size = (required_h - a_h)//2
hor_pad_size = (required_w - a_w)//2
centered = np.pad(a, [(vert_pad_size,vert_pad_size),(hor_pad_size,hor_pad_size)], mode='constant')
print(centered)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Explanation: I first calculate how many rows/columns must be added to up, bottom,left,right to get desired shape and then do it using `pad`. Keep in mind that this solution assumes all dimension of original array and desired array are odd.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you could assign slices:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.ones((5,5))
>>> B = np.zeros((3,3))
>>> A
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
>>> B
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
>>> A[1:-1, 1:-1] = B
>>> A
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Calculating the indices for the slice is left as an exercise.